# Which is better performance vise, shuffle and then array_slice, or array_rand?

Tags: php

So lets take this code:

```
shuffle($pushed_products_items);
$pushed_products_items = array_slice($pushed_products_items, 0, 7);
```

Versus this:

```
$pushed_products_items = array_rand($pushed_products_items, 7);
```

**Which one would be better performance vise?**

It would seem logical that the array_rand would be better, but if one thing I learned in my short career, not always things are the way it seems, and I am not really fond of testing this in production :)

Comment: take you less time to test this yourself, than to ask here

Comment: well if someone tested it already, why bother. But I suppose I can do it :)

Comment: "*why bother*" hope this is not your career choice, because that attitude sucks

Comment: Well I do obviously bother about which way is better, why else would I even post here. For godsake, if you don't like the question, just move on.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/Uvumt && http://3v4l.org/smpgg && http://3v4l.org/2kuQN

Comment: highlighted the real question

Answer (score 1):

Well I wrote the following tests:

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$arr = array(12, 554, 54, 68, 54, 564, 45, 545, 87, 878, 5454, 545, 55, 9898, 98, 87, 21, 21, 54, 54, 87, 98, 54, 54, 99,);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $tmp = array_rand($arr, 7);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

And this:

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$arr = array(12, 554, 54, 68, 54, 564, 45, 545, 87, 878, 5454, 545, 55, 9898, 98, 87, 21, 21, 54, 54, 87, 98, 54, 54, 99,);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    shuffle($arr);
    $tmp = array_slice($arr, 0, 7);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

So shuffle + array_slice on avg takes 5.2s for 1mil iterations, and array_rand takes avg 3.2 seconds.

So, array_rand is indeed better.

Comment: It definately is. Another example here: https://gist.github.com/amalmurali47/9213340